# Change Field Order of Content Type in the database

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm using drupal 7.  The drag drop interface to re-order fields for a content type seems to be buggy.  When I ADD a new Content, i noticed that Translation Settings is always appearing in the middle of my custom defined fields.   I go to Structure>Content Type>MyContent to re-arrange my fields, but no matter how I sort the fields, when I go back to Add My Content, Translation Settings always appears between the 27th and 28th custom defined field.

So I'm thinking of making this change in the database somewhere.  Does anyone know which tables I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I saw this too. The `language` form element was added by locale module [in code](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale_form_node_form_alter/7). If you want to change the weight of this element you can create your hook `HOOK_form_node_form_alter()` and add `#weight` for `$form['language']`.

Comment: Great, the actual function name was `translation_form_node_form_alter`.